# Create thumbs only when a post is sticky or any other way?

Tags: sticky-post

I have a slider and I want to create thumb of specific sizes for my slider but only when the post post is sticky or if there is any other way so it won't create all these sizes I set for the slider for all the posts?

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you want new thumb size only for sticky post and for rest is same

1).define a new size using [add_image_size()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size) and use [is_sticky()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_sticky) to check post is sticky or not

```
add_image_size('thumb-sticky','your_width','you_height')
```

2.)and put if condition in your slider or whatever

```
if( has_post_thumbnail() ):
  //check post is sticky 
  if( is_sticky() ):
    //This post is sticky print new thumbnail size i.e 'thumb-sticky'
    the_post_thumbnail('thumb-sticky');
  else:
    //This post is not sticky print thumbnail.
   the_post_thumbnail();
  endif;
endif;
```

**EDIT:**

As you want to image size specific to sticky post then do as in above code and paste below code in `functions.php`

```
add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes','ravs_thumb_sticky');
function ravs_thumb_sticky($image_sizes){
    global $post;
    if( ! is_sticky( $post->ID ) )
        $image_sizes= array_values( array_diff( $image_sizes, array('thumb-sticky') ) );
return $image_sizes;
}
```

Above code simply remove image size thumb-sticky if your post is not sticky post , hence for this size thumbs not generate for post.

**Important Link**:

[intermediate_image_sizes](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/media.php#L493)

or you can use

[intermediate_image_sizes_advanced](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/image.php#L105)

Comment: I'm pretty sure your solution is wrong. If you add_image_size, WordPress will generate this size for every image. And if I understand Alex corectly, he doesn't want that.

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż i edited my answer hope it will work

Comment: Why should it work? It won't generate new image size, when it doesn't exist and post with thumbnail is marked as sticky. You have to make post sticky and then add images to it - I don't think it's comfortable solution.

Answer (score 0):

[Dynamic Image Resizer](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/dynamic-image-resizer/)

> This plugin changes the way WordPress creates images to make it generate the images only when they are actually used somewhere, on the fly. Images created thusly will be saved in the normal upload directories, for later fast sending by the webserver. The result is that space is saved (since images are only created when needed), and uploading images is much faster (since it's not generating the images on upload anymore).

I think it could help you. (I'm not sure if it still works though).

If you're using Multisite you can use TimThumb (or another resizing script like TimThumb) or write your own resizing function base on WordPress resizing API. You can find such function here: https://gist.github.com/seedprod/1367237 (I haven't used it, but it looks like it should work).

Comment: unfortunately I use multiste

Note: This plugin does not work on multisite setups, due to the way WordPress handles file serving in such situations (with ms-files.php).

Comment: Hmm... I guess you have to use some kind of resizing scripts then (TimThumb) or write your own dynamically resizing function based on WordPress resizing API. I found this function: https://gist.github.com/seedprod/1367237 (no tested so I'm not sure it will help you).